# await Task.Delay behaves weird in if function

Tags: c#, async-await, task

so im trying to create some text animation in a rich textbox.
i gues i can use timers for the same/maybe even better result but the syntax was kinda hard to understand (ive been programming for + - 50 houres now)

im usign the await Task.Delay method but it behaves different then expected

```
private async void WriteText(string text, int delay)
    {
        await Task.Delay(delay);
        rtbOutput.AppendText(text);
    }

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WriteText("string 1 \n", 1000);
        WriteText("string 2 \n", 2000);
        WriteText("string 3 \n", 500);
    }
//richTextBox reads
    //    string 3
    //    string 1
    //    string 2
```

while i want the program to wait the intended delay of WriteText("string 1" before running the second WriteText("string 2")

the programm seems to read the 3 methods very fast and only does the output at the delayed time.

i can work around this problem bij just adding the first delay to the second and it wil behave fine

but then i tried an if method

```
private async void WriteTextChain(string text, int delay, int chain)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < chain; i++)
        {
            rtbOutput.AppendText(text);
            await Task.Delay(delay);
        }
    }

 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WriteTextChain("string 1 \n", 1000, 3);
        WriteTextChain("string 2 \n", 300, 6);
    }
    /* output reads
        string 1
        string 2
        string 2
        string 2
        string 2
        string 1
        string 2
        string 2
        string 1
    */
```

and this output just blew my mind. what is happening?
i would expect 
string 2,  string 2, string 2, String 1 sequence

any ids anyone?

Comment: You need to `await WriteText(...)`. Also, have `WriteText` return a `Task` and mark the button's event handler with `async`. And [read](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html).

Comment: `async void` is a famously *bad* idea.  Use `async Task` instead.  Your `button2_Click` would need to be `async void`, because it's an event handler.  But outside of top-level forms-style event handlers that should never happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because once you fire async function, especially once returning void, it is executed in new context (can be on the same thread, but in most cases isn't).

You would need to change your code:

```
private async Task WriteTextChain(string text, int delay, int chain)
// returning Task allows you to await call to this function
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < chain; i++)
        {
            rtbOutput.AppendText(text);
            await Task.Delay(delay);
        }
    }

 private async void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await WriteTextChain("string 1 \n", 1000, 3); // await makes execution of next line to wait for this line completion
        await WriteTextChain("string 2 \n", 300, 6);
    }
    /* output reads
        string 1
        string 1
        string 1
        string 1
        string 2
        string 2
        string 2
        string 2
        string 2
    */
```

TPL library has quite a learning curve, but keep experimenting. It gets much better